# How to order fetched images from Firebase, from most recent to oldest?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a app where images are uploaded to firebase and then retrieved when pressing a button. However in firebase they are arranged in alphabetical order. How can I make the "posts" be arranged from newest to oldest post?
**My DB structure:**

```
    {
  "Posts" : {
    "ThisWouldBeRandomUID" : {
      "post:RandomUIDHere" : {
        "ImageUrl" : {
          "image1" : "https://URLHere",
          "image2" : "https://URLHere"
        }
      }
    },
  "users" : {
    "7AM0CeJ71tYON9NejziFZto16fk2" : {
      "email" : "dhhfhfhffhdh@hdhdhdjdh.hehdhdhdh",
      "password" : "dhdhdhhdhdhdhdhdhfhf"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I didnt see something like that function in exists in firebase, in my case after getting all the "post" data (it is arranged from oldest to new) I store the "data" returned from the real time database query in a object and using [reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) function in javascript I successfully sort the post from new old. Hope this helps

Comment: So this is true even if your database sorts the placement of say, authenticated users in alphabetic; order?

Comment: It depends on how you query your data, if you want it in alphabetical order and from newest to oldest you must formulate some kind of logic for that. See [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data) in query lists of data. It is the same on C++ though the syntax is difference but theory itself is the same

Comment: "it is arranged from oldest to new" mine changes order randomly. Is that due to teh logic?

Comment: probably yes on how you query your data

Comment: added more info to my question: I am essenntialy trying to display the images from newst to oldest. I am assuming that to do this teh database wpuld have to be ordered not in a;phabetical order but in order based on time of uploading. NO?

Comment: can you explain more about the design of your database? base from above i dont get why you need this `post:RandomUIDHere` where in fact you have already random uid here `"ThisWouldBeRandomUID" : {`

Comment: because I need a random userID and a random postID